# How to remove offending key in git when you try to push your changes?

Tags: ssh, git

I've done tons of search and tested different solutions, but gain no success!

When I want to push my codes, I receive the following error:

```
Warning: the ECDSA host key for 'git.mywebsite.ir' differs from the key for the IP address '164.138.23.11'
Offending key for IP in /home/alireza/.ssh/known_hosts:10
Matching host key in /home/alireza/.ssh/known_hosts:1
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
```

What should I do to remove this message every time I push my changes? Any idea?

[image: key list]

Answer (score 147, accepted):

It says:

> Offending key for IP in /home/alireza/.ssh/known_hosts:**10**

*So for some reason you have to delete **10-th** line in known_hosts.*

Run this command to delete 10-th line in known_hosts:

```
sed -i '10d' ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Or use `ssh-keygen`

```
ssh-keygen -R git.mywebsite.ir
```

Quote from man

> ```
>  -R hostname
>          Removes all keys belonging to hostname from a known_hosts file.
>          This option is useful to delete hashed hosts (see the -H option
>          above).
> ```

Comment: `ssh-keygen -R git.mywebsite.ir` solved my problem.

Comment: didn't work for me, it keeps on asking question.

Comment: sed -i '1d' ~/.ssh/known_hosts
 or manually removing the line no. did work for me

Comment: If you're running this in Terminal on a Mac, you'll have to do sed -i '' '10d' ~/.ssh/known_hosts to avoid the "extra characters at the end of l command" error because it requires an extension to be specified.

Comment: if you want to remove the key based on ip address: `ssh-keygen -R [ipaddress]:port`. example of removing key for 192.168.0.1 on port 3456: `ssh-keygen -R [192.168.0.1]:3456`

Comment: It wasnt working for me because there were 2 entries. One for the dns name and one for the ip address. You have to remove both

Answer (score 6):

When I got the messages:

> Offending key for IP in /home/myusername/.ssh/known_hosts:**12**
>
> Notice the line number - in my case - **12**

So open 'known_hosts' file and delete the **12**-th row.

For me this solved the problem.

P.s. Notice if you cannot find the .ssh folder - the **.ssh** folder is hidden and in order to see it from the file manager - you have to "Show hidden files and folders". In Linux Mint (and possible in your distro too) when in the file manager - there is a shortcut to show/hide hidden folders -> Ctrl+H

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit your known_hosts file (located in ~/.ssh/known_hosts) and remove an entry asociated with this address.

Comment: This IP address does not exist in known_hosts file.

Comment: That's right, there is probably an entry with git.mywebsite.ir URL and another IP address. You should remove this line from known_hosts and then new IP adress will be associated with this host name.

Comment: There is nothing as my site URL in known_hosts file. I cannot even find git in the file. Could you take a look at the picture above?